# How to avoid blanks while converting seconds to HH:MM:SS format in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to convert seconds to HH:MM:SS in DAX, but I am getting blanks in results for entire year though I have only limited monhts in data[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFePG.jpg)

Comment: Please update your question with source data and code you've tried.

Comment: HH:MM:SS = INT([Seconds] / 3600) & ":" &
RIGHT("0" & INT(([Seconds] - INT([Seconds] / 3600) * 3600) / 60), 2) & ":" &
RIGHT("0" & MOD([Seconds], 3600), 2)

Resulsts are
Jan ::
Feb ::
Mar :10:20
Apr :20:30
May ::
Jun ::
Jul ::
Aug ::
Sep 1:10:14
Oct ::
Nov ::
Dec ::

I havce values only for Mar, Apr and Sep the rest of the months should not come with blank time

Comment: please check the attached image for results

Answer (score 0):

Look at your visual, you have an hierarchy on the date. When you take of the hierarchy it woull only show the dates with a value:

[image]